# Firefox enabling font smooth

Tags: firefox

after some days to resolve this problem on firefox i can't, i have this problem for all of websites and rendering them, i just read all of problem like with this problem, all of them couldn'r resolve that

this is simple screen shot and that's not my website to change css to resolve that

**Firefox:**

[image]

by the way i reinstall firefox and i dont have any problem in google chrome

**Chrome:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**my problem resolved**

after installing 50 version of firefox and enabling `hardware accelerator` and upgrade that with builtin update manager my problem resolved